# Choosing vectors on a complex sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, complex-numbers, combinatorial-geometry

Consider a complex $t$ dimensional unit sphere.

Say we pick $n$ points on this with inner products in the set $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_r\}$ (we have $n$ inner products with value $1$).  Note the set elements do not have to be distinct.

Is it possible to pick a second set of $n$ points with inner products in the set $\{-a_1,-a_2,\dots,-a_r\}$ (we have $n$ inner products with value $1$)? That is if $v_iv_j = a_k$, I would like to have $w_iw_j=-a_k$.

How do you find such pairs of points?

Comment: You should clarify your question. Are we supposed to find $n$ points that satisfy the condition? Or are we supposed to prove the existence for any set of $n$ points?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496897/choosing-sets-of-vectors-on-a-complex-sphere

Comment: Can you complete your sentence of "Note the set"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm interpreting this question as "Given $\{v_i\}$ a set of $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{C}^t$, does there exist $\{w_i\}$, a set of $n$ vectors such that the inner products are negative ..."

I will assume that $ t \geq 2 $, which is the more interesting case. $t=1$ is easily dealt with.

In general, no.

For $n = 2$, if the points are $v_1, v_2$, then we can take $w_1 = v_1, w_2 = -v_2$, which satisfies the conditions.

For $n > 2$, if we pick the points $ v_i = (1,0,\ldots, 0)$, then we want $n$ points such that $w_i \overline{w_j} = -1$.

This implies that $0 \leq ( \sum w_i) (\sum \overline{w_i}) = n - n(n-1) =n(2-n)< 0 $

If you want $v_i$ to be distinct, then take a small perturbation of the above.

This gives that $|\sum w_i \overline{w_j} | \leq n$ is a necessary condition. It is not clear if this is a sufficient condition.

---

If the question is asking to find a set of $\{v_i\} $, then for $n \leq t$, simply take $v_i = e_i$, which is the unit vector in direction $i$. Then $v_i \overline {v_j} = \delta_{i,j}$, and hence we may set $w_i = v_i$ which satisfies $ w_i w_j = - 0 $ if $ i \neq j$.

I do not know if there are solutions for $n > t$.

Comment: $t=n$ and $v_i=(1,0,0)$ does not make sense. You have chosen $n=3$

Comment: @JAS Indeed, I was writing it up for $n=3$ initially, but the proof easily extends. I have changed it accordingly.

Comment: I dont want all my points to be same $v_i$.

Comment: My question is does there exist such $v_i$

Comment: @JAS As I said, take a small perturbation.

Comment: @JAs Are you asking for a set of $\{v_i\}$ such the the inner product of the rest are a negative? Or are you asking about the general case?

Comment: So you are saying we cannot get more than $2$ points?

Comment: related question:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496897/choosing-sets-of-vectors-on-a-complex-sphere