# Choosing sets of vectors on a complex sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, combinatorial-geometry, combinatorial-designs

Consider a complex $t$ dimensional unit sphere.

Can we have $t$ sets of $2^t$ vectors $v_{ij}\in \Bbb C^t$ on the sphere where $i=1$ to $t$ and $j=1$ to $2^t$ on this with inner products satisfying $\sum_{i=1}^tv_{ij}\overline{v_{ij'}}=0$ where $j\neq j'$ ($\overline{v_{ij}}$ is complex conjugate transpose of $v_{ij}$)? How do you find such pairs of points?

The sum of $t$ inner products of vectors have to be $0$ and not the inner products themselves.

We want $\{V_j\}_{j=1}^t$ be $2^t \times t$ complex matrices with rows of $V_j$ being the $2^t$ vectors $v_{ij}$ such that:$$V_1\overline{V_1}+V_2\overline{V_2}+\dots+V_t\overline{V_t}=tI$$ where $I$ is the identity matrix.

In the above $\overline{V_j}$ refers to complex conjugate transpose of matrix $V_j$.

Comment: Ah! I see what you're saying now :) I went ahead and removed my (now irrelevant) comments. You can do the same with the x to the far right of each comment, if you wish. Thanks for making the changes!

Comment: Does the problem have a positive solution?

Comment: I'm also not sure what you mean by "such pairs of points." Do you mean "such a set of vectors"?

Comment: Yes points on sphere are vectors.

Comment: Ok nevermind about my solution. I just saw the note about "sum of inner products" and realized that I still did't interpret your notation correctly.

Comment: The thing you are summing is the inner product of vectors from $\Bbb C^{2^t}$?

Comment: No, the row vectors are of size $t$ in $V_j$? I think your original answer kind of made sense. However you have to elaborate to check for bugs. It is too succinct.

Comment: No, my original answer assumed that each inner product was 0, not the summation.

Comment: Does this solve the problem? Sum of $t$ low rank matrices of rank $r$ cannot exceed $rt$ and hence $t^2<2^t$ is best possible.

Answer (score 1):

Let's just work on the real sphere.

**Hint:** If $(\sum v_{ij}) \cdot (1,1,\ldots 1) = \sqrt{nm}$, then $ \sum v_{ij} \times \sum v_{ij} = mn$ and thus $ \sum v_{ij} \times v_{ij'} = mn - mn = 0$.

It remains to show that some set of $mn$ vectors satisfy this condition. This follows by a continuity argument, and looking at the plane intersecting the unit sphere.

Note that the above is not a complete classification. For example, we could have used that the sum of absolute values of the terms is $\sqrt{mn}$, but this doesn't allow for the easy geometric interpretation of a sphere.

Comment: Please elaborate. Your argument is too succinct to follow. So there exists such matrices? Is that your conclusion? How small can $m$ be?

Comment: @JAS $m=1$ works, with the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Well true. I can observe that:) For $t$ a variable?

Comment: made the question more precise.

Answer (score 1):

Sum of $t$ low rank matrices of rank $r$ cannot exceed $rt$ (which is $t^2$ here) and hence $t^2<2^t=2^{{t}}$ and hence the value of $t$ has to be raised to $2^{\frac{t}{2}}$.